# how to handle zero divisor case using Option case class in Spark RDD

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, mapping, rdd

I'm trying to use the Option case class to handle zero denominators while calculating percentages in Scala Spark. The set of RDD looks like the following:

```
val counties = Array("New+York", "Bronx","Kings","Queens","Richmond")
val base_url = "https://health.data.ny.gov/resource/xdss-u53e.json?County="
val urls = counties.map(a => base_url+a)
val results = urls.map(u => scala.io.Source.fromURL(u).mkString)
val data_rdd = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(results)).rdd.map(r => (r(4).toString.slice(0,10), r(0).toString,r(3).toString.toInt,r(5).toString.toInt))
```

What I want to do is to return a tuple (date, state, percent), where percent is calculated by dividing the third element by the fourth element(i.e. use the first Int to divide the second Int). However, since some divisors are zero, I really need to use the Option case class to handle these cases, but I'm stuck with how to do so using Scala Spark.

The following is what I've tried:

```
data_rdd.map{ case (a,b,c,d) => (a,b,c/d)
      case _ => (a,b,0)}
```

This code gives me an error of :

```
<console>:28: error: not found: value a
             case _ => (a,b,0)}
```

Can anyone help me figure out a way to handle the zero-divisors using option case class? Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you trying to work with datasets?. In your code there isn´t any Spark reference, just a plain Scala Array

Comment: thanks for reply, Emiliano! Yes I'm working with a dataset. But i kinda have no idea about how to show the rdd data here...So i only pasted some parts of it

Comment: Hi Emiliano, I updated the question with the full dataset! now it works!

Comment: So, have you figured out how to handle the "division by zero" error?

Comment: haven't yet... :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scala.util.Try` for that. Basically, you can give it an input that might fail, and then turn it into an option. A simplified example looks like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import spark.implicits._
import scala.util.Try

val columnNames = Seq("String", "Int1", "Int2")
val df = Seq(
  ("Alex", 3, 4),
  ("John", 1, 2),
  ("Alice", 7, 0),
  ("Mark", 5, -3)
).toDF(columnNames: _*)

val output = df.map{
  row => {
    // Dividing int1 by int2
    val division = Try(row.getInt(1) / row.getInt(2)).toOption

    // Creating a new row with an extra element: division
    (row.getString(0), row.getInt(1), row.getInt(2), division)
  }
}.toDF(columnNames :+ "division": _*)

output.show                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
+------+----+----+--------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|String|Int1|Int2|division|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
+------+----+----+--------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|  Alex|   3|   4|       0|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|  John|   1|   2|       0|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
| Alice|   7|   0|    null|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|  Mark|   5|  -3|      -1|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
+------+----+----+--------+
```

This division does not fail when it happens, it just creates a `null` entry in your row.

I used `Dataframes` for this since it's my preferred API but you can do just the same for RDDs.

Hope this helps!